# Can I have 3 events in javascript in single element?

Tags: javascript

I want a button for close, open navigation with animation

```
<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this);openNav();closeNav();">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

`myFunction(This)` is the animation function. all the function work fine. but if I combine them in one elements it not work. the `openNav()` work, but the `closeNav()` is doesn't work. So can I have 3 events in single element?

Comment: @Leothelion: Actually, the above should work just fine for calling all three of those functions.

Comment: @ Mochamad: That `onclick` attribute handler will call all three of those functions assuming none of them throws an exception Please update your question with a [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to create a **runnable** example of the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, example of code below.

```
<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this);" 
onclick="openNav();" onclick="closeNav();">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```